# Is there a way to use browser's native gzip decompression using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, gzip

The backend server responds with a gzip file but without the 
`Content-Encoding: gzip header`. And I do not have control over the server so can't handle the issue server side.

What I need now is to decompress the gzipped file client side using javascript.

I have found this excellent library which can help me do this: http://nodeca.github.io/pako/

But I don't want to add additional library just to un-gzip a file. I feel that there should be a way to use the browser's native functionality to un-gzip. Am I correct? If I am wrong can someone explain why this browser functionality is not exposed as a javascript API? And is there a way to un-gzip a file in javascript without adding an additional library?

Comment: As far as I know you can't *force* a browser to un-gzip a page with javascript since you don't control how the browser renders the page.

Comment: I make a get ajax request to fetch the file

Comment: That's all good but if the server is not outputting the headers that match the content-encoding I believe you will have to manually un-gzip.

Comment: I think the question is exactly about manually un-gzip, a resource fetched via ajax request not an entire page

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Compression Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Compression_Streams_API) is a new web standard and is currently available in Chromium, Firefox, Safari, and Deno.

Some example usage of the Compression Streams API:

```js
async function decompressBlob(blob) {
  let ds = new DecompressionStream("gzip");
  let decompressedStream = blob.stream().pipeThrough(ds);
  return await new Response(decompressedStream).blob();
}
```

And for compression:

```js
const compressedReadableStream = inputReadableStream.pipeThrough(new CompressionStream('gzip'));
```

You can also use a [WASM implementation](https://github.com/ColinTimBarndt/wasm-gzip). [Apparently](https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/207#issuecomment-540275814) WASM implementations can approach 90% of the performance of a native implementation (and ~20x the speed of a JS implementation).

See also:

- [WICG standards doc for Compression Streams API](https://wicg.github.io/compression/)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a ton.  Also, depending on your application, you might be able to convert directly without making a blob.  What worked for me: `let ds = new DecompressionStream('gzip'); let decompressed_stream = response.body.pipeThrough(ds); let decompressed_text = await new Response(decompressed_stream).text();`